# reverse lookup(ctrl+shift+r) not working on MAC OSX Lion?

Tags: linux, macos

I have been using reverse lookup(ctrl+shift+r) in a terminal, on mac or linux for years, but since upgrading to Lion it seems to have stopped working.

Does anyone have a fix?

Have others experienced similar?

Comment: Are you still using bash?

Comment: CTRL-R or CTRL-SHIFT-R? CTRL-R works for me in Lion.

Comment: yes, bash, my issue was the shift key! CTRL-R works fine.

Answer (score 10):

The shortcut for this feature is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, without the <kbd>Shift</kbd>.